# JMock unexpected invocation with weird invocation parameter

Tags: java, generics, jmock

Given:

```
A<T>
B extends A<String>

IMyInterface {
  List<T> myMethod(A<T>)
  List<String> myMethod(B)
}
```

When running a test that calls

```
foo = myMethod(new B());
```

I get this JMock error

```
unexpected invocation: IMyInterface.myMethod(<{}>)
```

Does anybody know what **(<{}>)** mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMock uses the `toString()` implementation of each object that it received when it's formatting the error message so what you're seeing is probably a result of the implementation of `toString()` in your `B` class. JMock adds the angle brackets so I'd say `B.toString()` is returning `"{}"`.